# OpenModelica - All examples including EnergyPlus_9_6_0 fail

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, energyplus

I've started to play around with OpenModelica and it's Building library version 10.0.0. I am trying to figure out possibilities to create and simulate HVAC system in OpenModelica with building created in EnergyPlus however, I've been experiencing some issues.

I tried all examples in Buildings.ThermalZones.EnergyPlus_9_6_0, but whenever I start a simulation I get following error: Process crashed Simulation process failed. Exited with code 0xffffffffc0000135.

When I look at the error section, translation error appears stating following:[Buildings.BoundaryConditions.WeatherData.ReaderTMY3: 880:29-947:86]: Variable weaBus.TDryBul not found in scope ReaderTMY3.
I've looked into ReaderTMY3 in both diagram and text view and it seems that temperature TDryBul is present and connected properly but somehow misread by programme.

I work with 64bit Windows 10 and I have tried to install openmodelica official release 1.22.1 as well nightly build 1.23.0-dev, but it does not make any difference when trying to run models involving Energy+. All other models I tried which do not involve use of Energy+ work perfectly.

Comment: Looking in our library coverage it seems those models work in Linux: https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/master/Buildings_latest/Buildings_latest.html. They seem to have problems in windows. It could be that the external libraries needed for running those models are not available for Windows. I will check.

Comment: Reading here https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/download.html it seems the external libraries are built using Visual Studio but OpenModelica uses Clang/Gcc for compilation and linking. I guess these could be incompatible.

Comment: @AdrianPop, thanks for answer. Do you think there is any solution to this without installing linux on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

I have now tested it and it seems to be working. To make it work you need to:

1. Download the windows zip from here and unzip it someplace, say `C:\dev\`
   https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/releases/v10.0.0/help/Buildings_ThermalZones_EnergyPlus_9_6_0_UsersGuide.html#Buildings.ThermalZones.EnergyPlus_9_6_0.UsersGuide
2. add the directory: `C:\dev\Spawn-light-0.4.3-7048a72798-win64\bin` to your PATH variable. This is needed so the simulation executable can find and start spawn.exe
3. add the directory: `%APPDATA%\.openmodelica\libraries\Buildings 10.0.0\Resources\Library\win64` to your PATH variable. This is needed so the simulation executables can find `ModelicaBuildingsEnergyPlus_9_6_0.dll`
4. start OMEdit and simulate one of the EnergyPlus models

Alternatively you could also create an OMEdit.bat file containing:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\dev\Spawn-light-0.4.3-7048a72798-win64\bin;%APPDATA%\.openmodelica\libraries\Buildings 10.0.0\Resources\Library\win64
"%OPENMODELICAHOME%"bin\OMEdit.exe
```

and run that.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for answer, unfortunately I did not manage to make it work. Just out of curiosity, was making a path to ModelicaBuildingsEnergyPlus_9_6_0.dll (step 3) neccessary in your case to run simulation? When I follow Buildings.ThermalZones.EnergyPlus_9_6_0.UsersGuide.Installation from link in your comment, it is suggested to set up xyz/Spawn-light-0.4.3-7048a72798-win64/bin as path without anything about setting up another path to dll file.

Comment: You need both paths as the simulation executable will need to find the dll that starts and connects to the Spawn server. That dll is in the library. OpenModelica should probably add that path by default when running the model but we don't